# Error Code 11402 when setup the Linked Service to Local C Drive folder

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to setup a linked Service to my local Drive folder. I installed the Microsoft Integration runtime in my laptop. Installation went fine without any problem.
Afterward, I change the sharing property to folder.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZRta.png)

Reinstall the Microsoft Integration Runtime.
Change the Sharing property of the folder to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to create file system linked service I got the same error.

[image]

I run PowerShell as administrator and Disable security validation to enable access to file system of the local machine using below command

```
 cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Integration Runtime\5.0\Shared\"
 .\dmgcmd.exe -DisableLocalFolderPathValidation
```

[image]

The linked service tested successfully.

[image]